# Magit equivalent of `git branch -D -r origin/feature/someLabelHere`

Tags: magit

On the command-line, I often do this

```
git branch -D -r origin/feature/someLabelHere
```

to remove a remote branch after a pull request from that branch has been merged into master.  I know now to do

```
git branch -d feature/someLabelHere
```

in magit, but not the `-D -r` equivalent.   How can one?

Simply pressing `k` to ask for removal on the displayed remote branch gets 
an error message and reference to the process buffer where one sees *e.g.*

```
  1 git … push origin :bugfix/someLabelHere        
error: unable to delete 'bugfix/someLabelHere': remote ref does not exist  
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:eddelbuettel/somerepo.git'
```

*Edit:* It may have been an 'order of commands' issue.  Deleting in magit *before* removing the remote branch at github seems to do the trick.

Comment: I don't understand the question, deleting remote and local branches works the same way in magit.

Comment: For the local one, it works as expected as you say.   But if I hit 'k' on the remote branch, I get an error message with a reference to the magit buffer.  So the pressing 'k' does not translate to command I want to be executed.  Hence my question here.

Comment: Please add this info (and the exact error message) to the question.

Comment: Hence, I had to go and dig -- but I found one thanks to `emacs --daemon` and long-running sessions...

Comment: I think that you need to prune the remote (`f-p<remote>`).

Comment: You mean  the `-p` switch in the `magit-fetch-popup` for `prune deleted branches` popup? Interesting, will try.  But seems circular as I do manage to delete it in the first place.

Comment: Yep, that's the flag I was suggesting.  You should be able to
typically delete remote branches as you would local (i.e. `k`).  But
if your local machine's info isn't up-to-date (say because the
remote branch was deleted from another machine), then you'd have to prune.

Comment: Not the use case. Remote branch very much present.  I essence: I add a local feature branch, push it to github, pull request and merge. Then I clean up -- and the removal of the remote branch fails.  I fear your suggestion may not be it.  But I will try and report back.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I'm confused.  If the remote branch exists, `k` should work.  You say that from the command line you do `git branch -D -r origin/feature/someLabelHere`.   But that alone isn't sufficient to delete a remote branch. If the branch exists in the remote and you do that, it will just be recreated on the next fetch.

Comment: Oh, it very much *is* sufficient, and *no*, a fetch does not re-create it. I have done literally hundred+ times.

Comment: If your statement is that `git branch -D -r <remote>/<branch>` will delete a branch *on* the remote, rather than just '.git/refs/remotes/<remote>/<branch>' in the local repo, I think you're mistaken.  Anyway, if you have a case where `k` in Magit cannot delete a branch that `git push <remote> :<branch>` can, please report it on the issue tracker so that we can figure out what's happening.  Thanks!

Comment: I will expand the question next time I work on a PR in one of my repos.  It is _exactly as I originally posited_: there is a valid git command I regularly do on the command-line.  And it is just about the last one I cannot do in magit as I get the very error I reported.

Comment: "[`git branch -D -r`] very much is sufficient [to delete remote branches]" - not according to [the manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch): "it only makes sense to delete remote-tracking branches if they no longer exist in the remote repository"

Comment: Yes, no need to keep dangling references.  It just bloats `git branch --all` with pointless references.  Hence my desire to remove them.

Comment: Puzzle solved, I think:  _if_ I tried to delete the branch from magit _before_ removing it at GitHub, all is well.

Comment: "if I tried to delete the branch from magit before removing it at GitHub, all is well": In other words, your claim that the "[r]emote branch [is] very much present" was not correct, and the problem is indeed that you are trying to delete a branch on the remote that no longer exists, as the git error message says and as I described above.

Comment: Quite possibly.  The operation that failed on me was tried a dozen+ times -- but seemingly I always removed the remote side first. I then tried to remove the _local_ index of that remote, and that failed on me. Quite possibly my bad as may not have pulled all remote references.  My main beef was this: I have a working flow on the command-line (where the remote-removed seemingly does not matter) and I failed to get all of it to magit.  I am not saying magit has a bug -- I am merely stating what we all know: git is complex, and documentation is hard.

Comment: Just wanted to say (once more) Thanks! as I have adopted this to my workflow.  After all it was maybe "just" the missing `--prune` that I really needed, but the docs had never let me to this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edit: The below description is of course still accurate, but it should be noted that Magit now falls back to deleting just the local remote-tracking ref if the respective branch does not actually exist on the remote anymore.

---

Pulling out the relevant information from the question comments:

Magit does not provide a direct equivalent of `git branch -D -r <remote>/<branch>`.
The `--prune` flag from the fetch popup (by default, <kbd>f-p</kbd>)
can be used instead to delete all stale remote-tracking for a
particular remote.

I believe that Magit doesn't provide a command for `git branch -D -r`
because it is the assumed that it would be rare for a user to want to
delete a single stale remote-tracking branch but not prune other stale
remote-tracking branches for that remote.

---

If the branch does still exist on a remote, <kbd>k</kbd> will run
`git push <remote> :<branch>`, deleting the branch on the remote and
cleaning up the local remote-tracking branch.  So, provided that
the branch hasn't been deleted from the remote in some other way
(e.g., through GitHub's web interface or by running `git push <remote> :<branch>`
from another machine), this command is all you need to run (at least
until you get on another machine and want to prune the remote-tracking
branches there).

Unlike `git push <remote> :<branch>`, `git branch -D -r <remote>/<branch>`
is not sufficient to delete the branch on the remote.  This is
described in `man git-branch`:

```
Use -r together with -d to delete remote-tracking branches. Note, that it only makes
sense to delete remote-tracking branches if they no longer exist in the remote
repository or if git fetch was configured not to fetch them again. See also the prune
subcommand of git-remote(1) for a way to clean up all obsolete
remote-tracking branches.
```

The example below shows what the above quote is talking about.  If you
just use `git branch -D -r`, the local remote-tracking branch will
deleted just to be recreated on the next fetch.

```
set -x

# Repo setup

mkdir remote-repo
cd remote-repo
git init --bare

cd ..
mkdir local-repo
cd local-repo

git init
echo text > some-file
git add some-file
git commit -m"Add some file"
git checkout -b feat master
echo text > feat-file
git add feat-file
git commit -m"Add feature file"
git remote add origin ../remote-repo
git push origin feat master

# branch -D -r test

git branch -D -r origin/feat
ls .git/refs/remotes/origin/

git fetch origin
ls .git/refs/remotes/origin/
```

But a `git push origin :feat` (or, in Magit, <kbd>k</kbd> and then
selecting `origin/feat`) will get rid of the branch in both places.

```
git push origin :feat
ls .git/refs/remotes/origin/

git fetch origin
ls .git/refs/remotes/origin/
```

Comment: "...because it is the assumed that it would be rare...". Yes, but we might still want to `(if (member branch ls-remote) (push :branch) (branch-D branch))`.

Comment: @tarsius yes, worth considering.  I suppose the main downside of that is needing to reach out to the remote a second time.  (And I suppose getting the error from git is a good indication that the remote may need pruning in general.)

Comment: Try-catch might be better, but is also more work.

Comment: I've opened an issue for this: https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/2778.

Comment: In favour -- one other case where this bites me sometimes is _two_ machines working on the same branch, call'em _desktop_ and _laptop_. If I do the procedure (in the all-important right order I now learned about) on the desktop I still have a pending branch on the laptop I can only nuke from the command-line.  Not ideal, so in favour of extending magit for that.